# How to send heroku logs to discord via webhooks?

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.js, heroku-cli

I saw heroku cli and it's cool to log in real time via `-tail`
But how do I send that real time logging to discord via webhooks (for example curl or node-fetch by cli or coding respectively.)?

Comment: Discord is not a logging service and using it that way is against their Terms of Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ps: the best way is here, and it works!
Module file:

```js
const {fetch} = require("rovel.js");
function log(text){
 fetch(process.env.CONSOLE_LOG, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
   "username": "RDL console.log",
   "content": text
  })
 })
 globalThis.logg(text);
}

function error(text){
 fetch(process.env.CONSOLE_LOG, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
   "username": "RDL console.error",
   "content": text
  })
 })
 globalThis.logerr(text);
}

function warn(text){
 fetch(process.env.CONSOLE_LOG, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
   "username": "RDL console.warn",
   "content": text
  })
 })
 globalThis.warnn(text);
}
module.exports = {log, error, warn};
```

And import it:

```js
const loggy = require("@utils/loggy.js");
globalThis.logg = console.log;
globalThis.console.log = loggy.log;
globalThis.logerr = console.error;
globalThis.console.error = loggy.error;
globalThis.warnn = console.warn;
globalThis.console.warn = loggy.warn;
globalThis.fetch = rovel.fetch;
```

(rovel.fetch is actually a copy of node fetch.)
`process.env.CONSOLE_LOG` is the discord webhook where you want to log it.

Answer (score 1):

So the only way I have been able to do this is to create a Heroku webhook through their notifications and have it go to Zappier then to a discord webhook.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to create a custom logdrain and connect that to the your heroku app's logplex. But you don't need to do that from scratch, this repository has a very good explanation and implementation in python

https://github.com/abhi887/heroku2discord-logdrain